# Kotlin data class overhead

Tags: kotlin

According to the official doc, a Kotlin data class has the following generated functionalities:

- `equals()`/`hashCode()` pair
- `toString()`
- `componentN()` functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration
- `copy()`

Now I understand that these functions are useful sometimes, I feel that in a lot of cases they are not necessary becase regular Kotlin classes already have auto-generated setters and getters. For example, in a Spring controller, if I want to create a DTO class to store and validate the request body, a regular Kotlin class (with validation annotations) seems enough.

I like that `data class` conveys the semantics that this class is a dumb data container, but I'm concerned that overusing data classes when we don't need their genereted goodies can negatively impact the code size & thus speed. Is there anything (such as an official style guide) that touches on this?

Comment: have you reached a bottleneck? The JVM compiler is optimized very well for such cases, and things like hashCode() are also used internally. If you are concerned about size and speed then you might want to choose another programming language.

Comment: Functions don't have overhead if you don't call them... It's not clear what you think the problem might be.

Comment: @Daniel No, I have not done any benchmarking or have the need to optimize whatsoever for my specific project. The reason I ask this question is, I feel `data class`es are a very convenient tool, and when I need a POJO my first reaction is to reach for a `data class` because I thought of them as `struct`s in languages like C++, which is absolutely NOT true because `data class`es actually have more overhead than regular classes. I'm just thinking, in a large codebase, if everyone reaches for `data class`es blindly, there can be a lot of dead generated code.

Comment: @underscore_d As I explained in the question, my concern is the unused functions generated by data classes can increase code size, which absolutely can degrade performance.

Comment: data classes have some nice features like multiple assignment binding, but in general they are used to introduce clear distinction between a class that contains only data and classes that can be either abstract or have methods. You should not concern yourself with performance since JVM compiler will strip everything that is unused, after all the classes are just abstractions.

Comment: @Daniel I think the concern is not runtime performance but the size of the compiled code on disk.

Comment: if you want to minimize compiled code you should use a system similar to the one on android: proguard, it strips all the unused classes from the code and obfuscates and minifies it.

Comment: It depends on the particular JVM implementation, but AIUI none of the Sun/Oracle JVMs since HotSpot do any compilation, optimisation, or other processing on methods until they've been executed some non-zero number of times.  Before that, the only overheads are likely to be insignificant extra time when loading the class, and insignificant extra memory holding its bytecode.  If you're concerned about memory usage or CPU time, **do some profiling** — but you'll almost certainly find no significant difference between `data` and non-`data` versions of a class.